# Define algorithmicx block without line numbers

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx

I'm trying to define some sort of algorithmicx command to give me this:

```
\Statex \textbf{Local State:}
\Statex \hspace{\algorithmicindent} $v \gets []$
\Statex \hspace{\algorithmicindent} $h \gets \bot$
```

[image: goal]

I've tried

```
\algloopdefx{LocalState}{\textbf{LocalState:}}
```

which results in a line number in front of **Local State:**, and I've tried

```
\algloopdefx{LocalState}{\Statex\textbf{LocalState:}}
```

but that results in blank line with a line number (probably because the `\algloopdefx` macro puts a `\State` at the beginning of the `<start>` line.

Is there any way to produce the sample above without resorting putting an `hspace` at the beginning of every line or similar dirty hacks?

**EDIT:** Adding MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm, algorithmicx, algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]

\Statex \textbf{Local State:}
  \Statex \hspace{\algorithmicindent} Foo
  \Statex \hspace{\algorithmicindent} Bar
\Statex

\Procedure{Foobar}{}
  \State Numbering should start at this procedure
\EndProcedure

\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I should note that I'm using the algpseudocode layout

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  If you could provide a [MWE](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-minxampl.html),
that will save the time of others.

Comment: @SunilkumarKS Done.

Answer (score 2):

Just define new macro, say `\StateX` as follows, that will solve the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm, algorithmicx, algpseudocode}

\newcommand\StateX{\Statex\hspace{\algorithmicindent}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]

\Statex \textbf{Local State:}
  \StateX  Foo
  \StateX  Bar

\Procedure{Foobar}{}
  \State Numbering should start at this procedure
\EndProcedure

\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And then StateX is redefined permanently. Looks like I'll probably have to make some macros like StartLocalState, EndLocalState that keep the old StateX in a temp